How can I use python (PyQGIS) to create a layer then set a field to use the Value Map widget type and then export it as a geopackage?
I have created a layer in python with 3 fields: fields = [QgsField("name", QVariant.String),QgsField("code", QVariant.String),QgsField("email", QVariant.String)]  As per this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456730/use-pyqgis-to-load-value-map-against-attribute, I have tried to give the code field a Value Map (widget type):
# Set widget type for the "code" field
code_field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName("code")
widget_setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup('ValueMap', {'Map': {'1': 'Option 1', '2': 'Option 2', '3': 'Option 3'}})
layer.setEditorWidgetSetup(code_field_index, widget_setup)

I print each field's widget type (field.editorWidgetSetup().type()) and as wanted the code field has widget type 'ValueMap'.
However when I export the layer to a geopackage:
# Export layer to GeoPackage
export_path = "path/to/your_geopackage.gpkg"
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, export_path, "UTF-8", layer.crs(), "GPKG")

And drag teh resulting geopackage into QGIS the code field has the 'TextEdit' widget type instead of 'ValueMap'. What went wrong?
I have tried reading the PyQGIS documentation on QgsEditorWidgetSetup but found nothing to help.

The issue you're encountering is due to the nature of GeoPackages and how QGIS handles field formatting.
The QgsEditorWidgetSetup class defines the field formatter and editor widget used for a field at a specific index in QGIS. However, when you export your layer to a GeoPackage, the GeoPackage format does not retain QGIS-specific field formatting.
A GeoPackage is essentially a SQLite database, and it is designed to store spatial data. It can store attribute data and restrictions, but it does not support storing QGIS-specific configurations such as field widget types. These configurations are specific to a QGIS project and are not part of the GeoPackage standard.
You will need to reapply your first section of code when loading a geopackage. I suggest making an import button so that you can always load a geopackage with your Qgis-configuration in mind.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
